# Importing Excel using OLEDB not bringing in collapsed groups

Tags: c#, excel

I've created a program to mine and import data from about 75 spreadsheets into an oracle table. I'm able to connect, iterate through sheets, and grab cells and rows seemingly fine. The problem is if the excel sheet was saved with grouped rows collapsed, it skips the rows. 
I can't find anywhere if there is an extended property or reg setting to allow me to possibly expand the groups on entry? Not sure how to getting around a collapsed group (not merged cell , those I can process without a problem).

code bits :

```
//Starting where I iterate through a particular sheet

var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source={0};    Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;ReadOnly=0\"", fileName);
OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

try
{   
objConn.Open();
System.Data.DataTable dt = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });

if (dt != null)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,F10,F11,F12 FROM [" + row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "]", connectionString);
        var ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            adapter.Fill(ds, "anyname");
        }
        catch
        {
            break;
        }
        DataTable data = ds.Tables[0];
        int rownum = 0; 

        // <a bunch of variable declarations>

        foreach (DataRow row_b in data.Rows)
        {
            // start slogging through the rows
            rownum = rownum++;
            // <reset some variables>
            if (rownum == 1) // Catch valid scripts that contain a number
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in data.Columns)
                {
                    if (column.ToString() == "F1")
                    {
                    // <processing code for this column>
                    }
                    if (column.ToString() == "F2")
                    {
                    //  <processing code for this column>
                    }
                    if (column.ToString() == "F3")
                    {
                    //  <you get the picture>
                    }
                }
        }
            if (rownum == 3)
            {
                // <moving along through the rows...different processing>
            }
                // <..rows 4-11..>

            if (rownum > 12 )
            {
                // <more value assignment>
            }

            string allvals = APPLICATION + E_USER + STEP_DESC + VARIATIONS + STATUS + STOPS_TESTING + ISSUE_NUM + ISSUE_COMMENTS + ADDITIONAL_INFO;
            allvals = allvals.Trim();

            //Don't want sheets that come across as Print Area this shouldn't affect the row processing 
            isPrintArea = 0;
            if (BOOKSHEET.Contains("Print_Area"))
            {
                isPrintArea = 1;
            }

            Boolean addornot=false;
            if (cb_forallscripts.Checked == true) 
            {
                addornot = (STEP_NUM != 0 &&
                allvals != "" &&
                isPrintArea == 0 &&
                SCRIPT_NUM != 0);
            }
            else
            {
                addornot = (STEP_NUM != 0 &&
                allvals != "" &&
                isPrintArea == 0 &&
                SCRIPT_NUM != 0 &&
                runScripts.Contains(SCRIPT_NUM.ToString()));
            }
            if (addornot)
            {
                //<connect to our Oracle db, I set up oCmd outside this> 
                OracleCommand oCmd = new OracleCommand();
                oCmd.Connection = oConn;
                oCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                oCmd.Parameters.Add("STEP_NUM", STEP_NUM);
                // <... bunch of parameters ...>
                oCmd.Parameters.Add("script", SCRIPT);
                oCmd.CommandText = "<My insert statement> ";
                oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch ( <error processing>)
{ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rows.OutlineLevel should be the VBA property you are looking for. It can be read or set. See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174260%28v=office.11%29.aspx) for Microsoft's rather terse description. Range.ClearOutline will, as it says, clear the outline for a specified range, as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223831%28v=office.11%29.aspx).